# How do you get selenium webdriver to return all HTML from website?

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape real estate listings from https://www.utahrealestate.com/search/map.search/page/1 and am having trouble getting selenium's webdriver to scrape all of the html.

From what I can tell the site is using a javascript function to dynamically load the listings on a map.

Instead of returning the HTML that contains the desired data underneath the  tag, it returns something like this:

```
<div id="results-listings">
<div style="height: 400px;"></div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<!--right ad zone-->
<div class="advert-160-600 advert-right-zone" data-google-query-id="CKDYtP2Ol-ECFVAMswAd7vcDAg" id="div-gpt-ad-1533933823557-0" style="">
<div id="google_ads_iframe_/21730996110/UtahRealEstate/ListingResults/Right-Side-160x600_0__container__" style="border: 0pt none; display: inline-block; width: 160px; height: 600px;"><iframe data-google-container-id="1" data-is-safeframe="true" data-load-complete="true" frameborder="0" height="600" id="google_ads_iframe_/21730996110/UtahRealEstate/ListingResults/Right-Side-160x600_0" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" name="" sandbox="allow-forms allow-pointer-lock allow-popups allow-popups-to-escape-sandbox allow-same-origin allow-scripts allow-top-navigation-by-user-activation" scrolling="no" src="https://tpc.googlesyndication.com/safeframe/1-0-32/html/container.html" style="border: 0px; vertical-align: bottom;" title="3rd party ad content" width="160"></iframe></div></div>
<div id="map_notification"></div>
<div id="map_markers_container" style="display: none;"></div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="advert-728-90" data-google-query-id="CKHYtP2Ol-ECFVAMswAd7vcDAg" id="div-gpt-ad-1533933779531-0" style="margin-top: 15px">
<div id="google_ads_iframe_/21730996110/UtahRealEstate/ListingResults/Center-Below-Map-728x90_0__container__" style="border: 0pt none;"><iframe data-google-container-id="2" data-load-complete="true" frameborder="0" height="90" id="google_ads_iframe_/21730996110/UtahRealEstate/ListingResults/Center-Below-Map-728x90_0" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" name="google_ads_iframe_/21730996110/UtahRealEstate/ListingResults/Center-Below-Map-728x90_0" scrolling="no" srcdoc="" style="border: 0px; vertical-align: bottom;" title="3rd party ad content" width="728"></iframe></div></div>
<div class="container" style="margin-top: 20px;">
<p style="margin: 20px 0 40px 0;">UtahRealEstate.com is Utah's favorite place to find a home. MLS Listings are provided by the Wasatch Front Regional Multiple Listing Service, Inc., which is powered by Utah's REALTORS®. UtahRealEstate.com offers you the most complete and current property information available. Browse our website to find an accurate list of homes for sale in Utah and homes for sale in Southeastern Idaho.</p>
<h5>Find Utah Homes for Sale by City</h5>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-7 five-three">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-4">
<b><a href="/davis-county-homes">Davis County</a></b>
<ul>
<li><a href="/bountiful-homes">Bountiful</a></li>
<li><a href="/clearfield-homes">Clearfield</a></li>
<li><a href="/clinton-homes">Clinton</a></li>
<li><a href="/layton-homes">Layton</a></li>
<li><a href="/kaysville-homes">Kaysville</a></li>
<li><a href="/north-salt-lake-homes">North Salt Lake</a></li>
<li><a href="/south-weber-homes">South Weber</a></li>
<li><a href="/syracuse-homes">Syracuse</a></li>
<li><a href="/woods-cross-homes">Woods Cross</a></li>
```

My current code looks like this:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

utahRealEstate = 'https://www.utahrealestate.com/search/map.search/page/1'
browser = webdriver.Chrome()
page = browser.get(utahRealEstate)
innerHTML = browser.execute_script("return document.body.innerHTML")

page_soup = soup(innerHTML)
page_soup
```

I am really after the information that is contained in the classes "listings-info-left-col" and "listings-info-right-col".

I am very new at this, so please dumb your explanation down as much as possible. I appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following calculates the pagination info (so as to be more flexible in case pagination info changes) and loops all the pages of the available results. It extracts price, property address and property details info into a list of lists, which is flattened, converted into a dataframe, and written out to csv. Regex is used to tidy up the output info. It uses wait conditions for info to be available.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import re
import math
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import pandas as pd

def getInfo(html): #function to return price and other listing info for the current page. Accepts the page source html as parameter
    soup = bs(html, 'lxml')
    items = soup.select('.inline_info')
    rowsToReturn = []
    for item in items:
        data = item.select('.list-info-content') #list containing address info and property details e.g. baths, beds
        price = item.select_one('h3').text.strip()
        address = re.sub('\s\s+', ' ',  data[0].text.strip()) #replace 2+ white space with single space
        propertyInfo = re.sub('\s\s+', ' ',  data[1].text.strip())
        rowToReturn = [price, address, propertyInfo]
        rowsToReturn.append(rowToReturn)
    return rowsToReturn

url = 'https://www.utahrealestate.com/search/map.search/page/1' #landing page
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(url)
WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".list-info-content"))) #wait for all listings content

reg = re.compile(r'(\d+)') #regex pattern looking for 1 or more numbers to be applied to class view-results which has the pagination and total results info
matches = reg.findall(driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.view-results').text) # [1,50,500] from 1 to 50 of 500
numResults = int(matches[2])
resultsPerPage = int(matches[1])
numPages = math.ceil(numResults/resultsPerPage)

results = []
results.append(getInfo(driver.page_source)) #add page one results

if numPages > 1: 
    for page in range(2, numPages + 1): #loop calculated number of pages 
        driver.get('https://www.utahrealestate.com/search/map.search/page/{}'.format(page)) #add new page number into url
        WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".list-info-content"))) #wait for all listings content
        results.append(getInfo(driver.page_source)) #add next page results

#flatten list of lists
finalList = [item for sublist in results for item in sublist]

df = pd.DataFrame(finalList, columns = ['price', 'address', 'property details']) #convert to dataframe and write to csv
df.to_csv(r'C:\Users\User\Desktop\Data.csv', sep=',', encoding='utf-8-sig',index = False )
driver.quit()
```

Example results:

[image]

Comment: Thank you QHarr, so from looking at my code, what was the main thing that I was missing to collect all of the information? Was it the WebDriverWait statement?

Comment: Hiya. So, yes that was definitely a key part. Is there anything else in the above you would like to have explained? I tried to annotate throughout the code.

Answer (score 0):

This code starts with the first page, parses it for the details then goes on to load the rest of the pages one at a time parsing them for the details until there are no more pages left. You can refine it, if you like, to suit you exact needs.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException

utahRealEstate = 'https://www.utahrealestate.com/search/map.search/page/1'
browser = webdriver.Chrome()
page = browser.get(utahRealEstate)


# parse the page
def parse(html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
    for i in soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'listings-info'}):
        print(i.get_text())


while True:
    try:
        # parse the current page.
        time.sleep(3)
        parse(browser.page_source)
        # Find the next page button and click it.
        browser.find_element_by_xpath("//a[text()='Next ']").click()
    except NoSuchElementException:
        # Couldn't find a next page button must have got to the end.
        break

browser.quit()
```

Outputs:

```
$615,000
3217 W 10305 S
South Jordan, UT 84095


5Beds
5Baths
4002Sq.Ft.
#1588082

Domain Real Estate LLC
...
```

Comment: Thank you Dan-Dev. The code worked very well, but I am still having trouble understanding why your code worked but when I try to run  

`browser = webdriver.Chrome()  
page = browser.get(utahRealEstate)  

soup = BeautifulSoup(browser.page_source, 'html.parser')  

soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'listings-info'})`  

It doesn't return anything. What is the main disconnect?

Comment: Add `time.sleep(3)` before `soup = BeautifulSoup(browser.page_source, 'html.parser')` and it will work. You need to wait for the page to load.